# Enumeration Type exception when attempting to filter a LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, exception

I'm trying to generate a grid that end-users can filter the data using several inputs.

To do this I'm attempting to filter an initial LINQ to Entities object as follows:

```
Dim servhist As IQueryable(Of servicesHistory) = db.servicesHistories

If cboProperty.EditValue <> Nothing Then
    servhist = servhist.Where(Function(p) p.propID = CLng(cboProperty.EditValue))
End If

grdServHist.DataSource = servhist.ToList()
```

However when I attempt to filter the query, I get the following error message when attempting to enumerate the collection: **"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."**

I'm at loss. I've done this w/out a problem using C#, but unfortunately cannot get it to go w/ VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the capture in the closure in your Linq Expression.

In English, this means you are trying to pass `CLng(cboProperty.EditValue)` into a Linq Expression. Which is legal. However when Linq to Entity Framework looks at that, it can't convert that into SQL. That expression contains:

1. A .net class (most likely a winform control I suspect)
2. A property call on the .net class
3. A .net conversion call on the result of the .net class.

Poor Linq2EF can't figure that stuff out! This however WILL work.

```
Dim servhist As IQueryable(Of servicesHistory) = db.servicesHistories

If cboProperty.EditValue <> Nothing Then
    Dim editValue = CLng(cboProperty.EditValue)
    servhist = servhist.Where(Function(p) p.propID = editValue)
End If

grdServHist.DataSource = servhist.ToList()
```

Now this looks exactly the same. However if you ask a Linq Ninja they will tell you the two are very different, since I have converted the `CLng(cboProperty.EditValue)` from a Linq Expression to a function call.

Personally I am in two minds about how Lambda Expressions have the same syntax as Lambda Functions, leading to these exceptions.

BTW I prefer my queries in this form...

```
Dim editValue = CLng(cboProperty.EditValue)
Dim servhist As IQueryable(Of servicesHistory) = _
    db.servicesHistories.Where(Function(p) p.propID = editValue or editValue is Nothing)
grdServHist.DataSource = servhist.ToList()
```

This allows you to then refactor the IQueryable into a compiled query.